# G-WAN URL rewrite for home page not working

Tags: url-rewriting, handlers, g-wan

I am trying to do a URL rewrite for the site home page. Here is a simplified version of my handler.

```
int init(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   u32 *states = (u32*)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES);
   *states =  (1 << HDL_AFTER_READ);
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
   xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, " / ", " /?home ");
   return 255;
}

void clean(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{}
```

Basically it is just replacing " / " with " /?home ". So when user loaded "www.domain.com" it will give them the content of "home.c". Here is the result of the rewrite. Everything looks right I am not sure what's causing the issue.

Original Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Rewritten Request:

```
GET /?home HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

After the rewrite this is the result.

```
GET http://localhost:8000/


 -- response --
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved on G-WAN version 4+

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return 255;` in the `main()` function.

Remember that connection handler return codes have a signification:

```
return 255; // execute next connection step
return   0; // close connection
```

Also, even if it remains empty, you must declare a `clean()` function in a connection handler:

```
void clean(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{}
```

Finally, you MUST test the handler state in `main()`.

This gives us the tested code below:

```
// ============================================================================
// Handler C script for the G-WAN Web Application Server (http://gwan.ch/)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main.c: basic rewrite example
// ============================================================================
#include "gwan.h"    // G-WAN exported functions

#include <stdio.h> // puts(), printf()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// init() will initialize your data structures, load your files, etc.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// init() should return -1 if failure (to allocate memory for example)
int init(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // define which handler states we want to be notified in main():
   // enum HANDLER_ACT { 
   //  HDL_INIT = 0, 
   //  HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT, // just after accept (only client IP address setup)
   //  HDL_AFTER_READ,   // each time a read was done until HTTP request OK
   //  HDL_BEFORE_PARSE, // HTTP verb/URI validated but HTTP headers are not 
   //  HDL_AFTER_PARSE,  // HTTP headers validated, ready to build reply
   //  HDL_BEFORE_WRITE, // after a reply was built, but before it is sent
   //  HDL_HTTP_ERRORS,  // when G-WAN is going to reply with an HTTP error
   //  HDL_CLEANUP };
   u32 *states = (u32*)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES);
   *states =  (1 << HDL_AFTER_READ);
   return 0;
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// clean() will free any allocated memory and possibly log summarized stats
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void clean(int argc, char *argv[])
{}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main() does the job for all the connection states below:
// (see 'HTTP_Env' in gwan.h for all the values you can fetch with get_env())
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // HDL_HTTP_ERRORS return values:
   //   0: Close the client connection
   //   2: Send a server reply based on a custom reply buffer
   // 255: Continue (send a reply based on the request HTTP code)
   const int state = (long)argv[0];
   if(state != HDL_AFTER_READ)
      return 255;

   xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
   printf("req_1: %.20s\n", read_xbuf->ptr);
   xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, " / ", " /?home ");
   printf("req_2: %.20s\n-------------------\n\n", read_xbuf->ptr);

   return 255; // continue G-WAN's default execution path
}
// ============================================================================
// End of Source Code
// ============================================================================
```

Comment: I modified my sample code. I got the clean and return 255 on my original code. But still same issue.

Comment: I rewrote the reply above to add the full (tested) source code.

Comment: Still the same. I used your code but I am using a virtual machine. That might cause the issue. I will try it from home tonight.

Comment: I got "req_2: GET /?home HTTP/1." after rewrite but still nothing.

Comment: Proof that the rewrite *handler* works. Now check the log files to see why the file is not served (404: not found?).

Comment: [Fri Nov 09 01:19:43 2012 GMT] [client 127.0.0.1] 0: "READ:Tmo 565 bytes:
" - That is the error message. home.c does exist and works fine.

Comment: It means that the HTTP request was incomplete (or broken by the rewrite). You should use **printf("req_2: %*v\n-------------------\n\n", read_xbuf->len, read_xbuf->ptr);** to see where in the hexdump made by this command.

Comment: Are you using 3.3.28? I used your tested code but still its not working on my machine. I am guessing its related to the length of request. My rewrite works when I am not adding char on the result like "/blog" to "/?log". But from "/" to "/?home" it doesn't.

Comment: I was using v3.11.9, to correct your v3.3 rewrite, use the "%*v" hexdump above to see where the rewrite is breaking the request (or wait for the next public release which works for me).

Comment: I did a compare on the re-written request and it is correct. I will just wait for the next release. Maybe this is just a 3.3 issue. I will try it again on next release. Thank you for your help.