# Gwan handler states

Tags: c, url-rewriting, handler, restful-url, g-wan

I'm trying to implement a restful handler for my scripts that replaces the `/` with `&` so I can turn url's like this: `?script.c&things` into this: `?script/things`. Currently I just have a test script that is based of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479044/g-wan-url-rewrite-for-home-page-not-working) post by Gil.

```
  // ============================================================================
  // Handler C script for the G-WAN Web Application Server (http://gwan.ch/)
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // main.c: basic rewrite example
  // ============================================================================
  #include "gwan.h"    // G-WAN exported functions

  #include <stdio.h> // puts(), printf()
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // init() will initialize your data structures, load your files, etc.
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // init() should return -1 if failure (to allocate memory for example)
  int init(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     // define which handler states we want to be notified in main():
     // enum HANDLER_ACT { 
     //  HDL_INIT = 0, 
     //  HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT, // just after accept (only client IP address setup)
     //  HDL_AFTER_READ,   // each time a read was done until HTTP request OK
     //  HDL_BEFORE_PARSE, // HTTP verb/URI validated but HTTP headers are not 
     //  HDL_AFTER_PARSE,  // HTTP headers validated, ready to build reply
     //  HDL_BEFORE_WRITE, // after a reply was built, but before it is sent
     //  HDL_HTTP_ERRORS,  // when G-WAN is going to reply with an HTTP error
     //  HDL_CLEANUP };
     u32 *states = (u32*)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES);
     *states =  (1 << HDL_AFTER_READ);
     return 0;
  }
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // clean() will free any allocated memory and possibly log summarized stats
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void clean(int argc, char *argv[])
  {}
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // main() does the job for all the connection states below:
  // (see 'HTTP_Env' in gwan.h for all the values you can fetch with get_env())
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     // HDL_HTTP_ERRORS return values:
     //   0: Close the client connection
     //   2: Send a server reply based on a custom reply buffer
     // 255: Continue (send a reply based on the request HTTP code)
     const long state = (long)argv[0];
     printf("Catching Gwan State: %i\n", (long)argv[0] );
     if(state != HDL_AFTER_READ)
        return 255;

     xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
     printf("req_1: %.20s\n", read_xbuf->ptr);
     xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/", "&");
     printf("req_2: %.20s\n-------------------\n\n", read_xbuf->ptr);

     return 255; // continue G-WAN's default execution path
  }
  // ============================================================================
  // End of Source Code
  // ============================================================================
```

In this script I have a `printf("Catching Gwan State: %lu\n", (long)argv[0] );` line that is supposed to print the state it gets (0-8, i guess), but it keeps printing

```
Catching Gwan State: -38241808
```

I have no idea what -38241808 is

Any Help? My OS is Linux Mint 14, Gwan version 4.2.19

[EDIT] Even when using the main_generic.c handler example that comes with Gwan gives these weird state values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to implement a restful handler for my scripts that replaces the / with & so I can turn url's like this: `?script.c&things` into this: `?script/things`.

G-WAN does it *automatically*. Handlers are absolutely not needed. That `RESTful` feature is documented in the PDF manual *and* the timeline.

You can even define which programming language is the default language (the one that does not needs explicit file extensions in URIs). See how to do it below (here from a handler):

```
int init(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // the QUERY_CHAR character can be chosen from the following set: 
   //  - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) 
   // (see RFC 2396, section "2.3. Unreserved Characters")
   //   
   u8 *query_char = (u8*)get_env(argv, QUERY_CHAR);
   *query_char = '!'; // use "/!hello.c" instead of "/?hello.c"

   // by default, DEFAULT_LANG = LG_C (ANSI C)
   // LG_C, LG_CPP, LG_JAVA, etc. are defined in /gwan/include/gwan.h
   // and in http://gwan.com/api#env
   //
   u8 *lang = (u8*)get_env(argv, DEFAULT_LANG);
   *lang = LG_CPP; // use "/!hello" instead of "/!hello.cpp"
   return 0;
}
```

Just test it with the `/?argv.c&123&456` G-WAN example using `/?argv/123/456` instead...

Comment: I feel like a fool. I have read the manual (many times) and I understood that you COULD implement a restful architecture, and you can change the default language, I hadn't realized it was already in place. Thank you very much Gil

Comment: I'd still like to know why the handler was getting strange values for future reference

Comment: I am now trying to use a handler to add a random value at the end of the url to avoid the micro-cache. But I am still recieving weird values for argv[0], I have updated to gwan v 4.3.1

Answer (score -1):

i tested it on mine.
if you do like this
 `u32 *states = (u32*)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES);`
 `*states = (1L << HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT)`
 `| (1L << HDL_AFTER_READ)`
 `| (1L << HDL_BEFORE_PARSE)`
 `| (1L << HDL_AFTER_PARSE)`
 `| (1L << HDL_HTTP_ERRORS)`
 `| (1L << HDL_BEFORE_WRITE);`

it will produced 0-8.

Comment: I restart everytime I update the handler (just to be sure), but still weird values